# Specifying a non-business range of hours to cron

Tags: unix, cron

Can you specify 5 PM to 8 AM to cron using `* 17-08 * * *`  ?

Or do I need two jobs with schedules  `* 17-23 * * *`  and `* 00-08 * * *`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67158/crontab-entry-with-hour-range-going-over-midnight

Comment: Thanks, that covers it.  Want to add an answer or do you think I should delete?